# Git pull with some extra folders/files on local as compared to git repository

Tags: github, git-pull

I have 5 folders and some files on my local project folder. And on git hub only 3 folders are there.

If I do git pull, Will other 2 folders/files from local will be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer, No. It will not get deleted.

If you don't want those files or folder to be committed. You should mention in `.gitignore` file. 
More info at : [.gitingnore docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and [Ignoring files on github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: In case of git push I don't want to push those folders and files to git. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can also *exclude* files/folders on your local copy of the repo by modifying `.git/info/exclude`, which won't be versioned.